# WSO2 IdentityServer, Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 IdentityServer 5.11.0 is showing the below error when starting the service. I am using MySQL as the data source.

### [2021-01-20 14:25:29,760] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex2.internal.DynamicCRMCustomMexComponent} - DynamicCRMSupport MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully.
[2021-01-20 14:25:34,420] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} - LDAP connection created successfully in read-write mode
[2021-01-20 14:25:34,589] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.consent.mgt.core.internal.ConsentManagerComponent} - ConsentManagerComponent is activated.
[2021-01-20 14:25:34,595] []  INFO {org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner} - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2021-01-20 14:25:34,962] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.x509Certificate.internal.X509CertificateServiceComponent} - X509 Certificate Servlet activated successfully..
[2021-01-20 14:25:36,240] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} - Configured Registry in 258ms
[2021-01-20 14:25:36,298] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} - Connected to mount at configregistry in 13ms
[2021-01-20 14:25:36,299] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} - Connected to mount at govregistry in 14ms
[2021-01-20 14:25:36,411] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO} - Failed to add properties to the resource /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.governance/media-types/index. Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value java.sql.SQLException: Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

### [2021-01-20 14:25:36,446] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils} - Unable to create fixed remote mounts. org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to add properties to the resource /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.governance/media-types/index. Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.put(MountHandler.java:299)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2505)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.put(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:204)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:950)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:705)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:591)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:840)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:73)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:816)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:813)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

```
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

### Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add properties to the resource /_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.governance/media-types/index. Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.addProperties(JDBCResourceDAO.java:1657)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.add(JDBCResourceDAO.java:461)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.add(Repository.java:1059)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.put(Repository.java:305)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:717)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:840)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:73)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:816)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:813)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:813)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.put(MountHandler.java:292)
... 55 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.addProperties(JDBCResourceDAO.java:1649)
... 66 more

### [2021-01-20 14:25:36,469] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} - Connected to mount at configregistry in 2ms
[2021-01-20 14:25:36,470] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} - Connected to mount at govregistry in 4ms
[2021-01-20 14:25:36,528] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} - Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2021-01-20 14:25:36,603] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO} - Failed to add properties to the resource /_system/governance/repository/security/certificate/validator/ocspvalidator. Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value java.sql.SQLException: Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)

### [2021-01-20 14:25:36,617] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.x509Certificate.validation.CertificateValidationUtil} - Error while adding validator configurations in registry. org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to add properties to the resource /_system/governance/repository/security/certificate/validator/ocspvalidator. Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.put(MountHandler.java:299)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2505)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.put(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:204)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:950)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:705)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:591)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:840)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:73)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:816)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:813)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

### Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add properties to the resource /_system/governance/repository/security/certificate/validator/ocspvalidator. Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.addProperties(JDBCResourceDAO.java:1657)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO.add(JDBCResourceDAO.java:461)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.add(Repository.java:1059)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.put(Repository.java:305)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:717)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:840)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:73)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:816)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:813)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.put(UserRegistry.java:813)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.put(MountHandler.java:292)
... 76 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)

[2021-01-20 14:25:43,957] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO} - Failed to add properties to the resource /_system/config/repository/transports/http/listener. Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value java.sql.SQLException: Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)

How to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you please attach more logs from the backend to this question?

Comment: Added few more logs.

Comment: Added few more logs. Check the URL.  https://jmp.sh/yWtHcM7